# Compute area of a trapezoid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]
In the figure, $ABCD$ is a trapezoid of bases $AB$ and $DC$. $P$ is the midpoint of $CE$. If the area of $\triangle DFC = 3$ and the area of  $AEPF = 21$, compute the area of $AECD$.

**My try**

I made a system of equation naming the areas of $AFD$ and $PFC$ $a$ and $b$, then I drew the height of $AECD$ and used it to compute the area of the triangles $\triangle ADC$ and $\triangle AEC$ and the trapezoid $AECD$ in function of my two variables $a$ and $b$, but I found that if I relation those areas, it's circular (I got an expression of the form $0=0$). I'm aware that I have to use the fact that $P$ is the midpoint of $CE$ but I don't know how.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$x + 2y = 21$

$\dfrac {3 + 2x}{3} = \dfrac {y}{x}$

Eliminating y from the above to get a quadratic in x, and x = ... = 3.

Comment: To get area CPB = 3 + x, you may have assumed EBCD is a parallelogram, which is not a given.

Comment: @Quanto I only assume that it can be proven since AB//CD and DP = PB.

Comment: How would you conclude DP = PB? I do not suppose it was given.

Comment: @Quanto It should be CP = PE instead. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But, CP = PE does not lead to areas CPB = CDP = 3 + x.

Comment: @Quanto After proven that it is a //gm, its diagonals will divide that //gm into 4 regions with the same area.

Comment: Got it, Appreciate it

Comment: @Quanto You are welcome. I did not include all the details because the OP is asking for hints.

Comment: My bad. I should have figured it out

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

P is the midpoint hence EBCD is a parallelogram.

The triangles ACD, BCD and EBC have equal area.